# Override for certain tag

Tags: ezpublish

I need to do an override for a certain tag, but I don't know how, since it is not something I can target with `node_id` or something like that. I tried using `url_alias`:

```
[eztag_search_2]
Source=tags/view.tpl
MatchFile=full/tags/view2.tpl
Subdir=templates
Match[url_alias]=tags/view/News/Important
```

But it doesn't work. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't override a template for a specific tag.
You'll have to create an override for `tags/view.tpl` without matching rules and specify rules in your template code.

Comment: I need two different views - for all the tags (that's `tags/view.tpl`) and for that specific one - for now I managed to use `if/else`, but it's very bad solution.

Comment: I understand but you just can't do it with classic override.

Answer (score 1):

Sylvain's right, you can't use the override system to manage different templates based on the tag itself.

Solution #1 : implement a template operator which will process a list of tags with a custom logic which will switch from a template to an other while display a tag.

Solution #2, which is not far from solution 1 : implement a `{tag_view_gui}` operator so that you can inherit from the template override mecanism. This is really not complicated, and I'll suggest that you have a look at the ezflow `{block_view_gui}` since it's a very simple one, decoupled into an extension.

See : https://github.com/ezsystems/ezflow/blob/master/packages/ezflow_extension/ezextension/ezflow/autoloads/eztemplateautoload.php